# Syncfusion listbox drag and drop not working when one of the list box is empty

Tags: listbox, syncfusion

I have the following code for drag and drop in syncFusion list box:

```
@Html.EJ().ListBoxFor(Model => Model.Inclusions).Width("100%").Datasource(Model.Inclusions).ListBoxFields(incl => incl.Text("Label").Value("TypeOfInclusionId")).AllowDrag(true).AllowDrop(true).Enabled(true).EnablePersistence(true)

@Html.EJ().ListBoxFor(Model => Model.Exclusions).Width("100%").Datasource(Model.Exclusions).ListBoxFields(excl => excl.Text("Label").Value("TypeOfInclusionId")).AllowDrag(true).AllowDrop(true).Enabled(true).EnablePersistence(true)
```

When the exlusion listbox contains at least one element, then I can do the drag and drop, but when the listbox is empty (any of them), then I cannot drag from listbox inclusion and drop in listbox exclusion and vice versa.

Any idea why?  The Model.Exlusion is not set to null.

Answer (score 0):

We suspect the issue might with model binding in Listbox. Please cross check if the Model values in listbox are bound properly.

You can find the runnable sample here for your reference.

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/220260/ze/ListBoxForMVC1365846797)